# An item with the same key has already been added when setting a value to entity object

Tags: frameworks, entity

I have a `SilverLight` application which uses entity `framework 4` for data access layer. I need to manually create some entity objects and later save to database.
I have this peculiar problem. When Instantiate the object and then assign some values to its property I got an error "An item with the same key has already been added". This is before the object is even added to the instance of `ObjectContext`. Also, before switching `to SP1 of Visual Studio`, there is no problem. It only happens after we upgraded the `VS2010 to SP1.`

In code, it is like this.

```
class cls = new class(); 
cls.class_name = "test";
```

The exception is thrown when class_name is assigned a value at run time. "class" is an entity object manually created and it maps to a table in th `SQL database`.

Where I should look to solve this problem?

Any help is greately appreciated.